# How to reference the recently updated row in an AFTER UPDATE trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

In `AFTER DELETE` and `AFTER INSERT` triggers you can reference the newly deleted/inserted row using `OLD.desired_id` and `NEW.desired_id`. But how do you reference the row in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger? For example, after I flip a switch in the row I need to get an ID from the row whose boolean I just flipped, so like `THIS.desired_id` or something?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, you can achieve it by following template query. Changes required as per your schema. Use table available inside triggers which is having content be updated into table.

```
ALTER TRIGGER 'trigger_name_afterupdate'
ON [*db*].[*table*]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [*db*].[*table*]
    SET last_updated_by = SYSTEM_USER
    **(your flip switch condition goes here)**
    FROM *db*.*table* x
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted i WHERE i.id = x.id);
END
```

Comment: I believe we can use either of `OLD.desired_id` or `NEW.desired_id` as `desired_id` will remain the same. It's just the boolean flag that would have different value for `OLD` and `NEW`.

Answer (score 0):

In an `INSERT` `FOR EACH ROW` trigger `new` references the inserted row. There's no deleted row, so `old` is useless.

It's the other way round, when the triggering action is a `DELETE`. Then `old` references the deleted row and `new`, in absence of an inserted row is useless.

If the action is `UPDATE` both `old` and `new` reference a row. `old` references the row before the change and `new` after.

So you'd either use `old.desired_id` or `new.desired_id` depending on the version you want, the one before the change or the one after.

Comment: A useful manual link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html